# Error :The Column 'code' is constrained to be unique. Value '3' is already present

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

I find this error when i change combobox index that have another combobox depend on it

```
Private Sub cmbcollege_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbcollege.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim sql As String = "select major ,code from major_code where code in (select major from college_major where college = " & cmbcollege.SelectedValue & ")"
    Dim dt As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, CON)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Try
        CON.Open()
        dt.Fill(ds)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        CON.Close()
    End Try
    Dim c As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To c
        cmbMajor.DisplayMember = "major"
        cmbMajor.ValueMember = "code"
        cmbMajor.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please use `SQL Parameters`..., turn `Option Strict On`... Also your issue is more than likely here: `where college = " & cmbcollege.SelectedValue & ")`.. Try changing that to: `where college = '" & cmbcollege.SelectedValue & "')"`

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through the code, what and how many rows if any is `ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count`? Also get rid of the `Dim c As Integer` you don't need it and also the loop...

Comment: there's a value inside ... 

5 ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count

Comment: And both `major` and `code` columns exist? With 5 records? Remove your loop all together, you do not need it also your Dim c statement you don't need that.

Comment: can u explain more :D

Comment: Also I have a feeling it's other code ***not related*** to the code you have shown...

Comment: Maybe ,,,  listen ,, we are trying to make two combobox depend on each other ... and i can't find where's the error :\

Comment: I think maybe the datatable already has data in it from a previous fill

Comment: I would then ***post all relevant code in question*** so I or someone else can better assist you.

Comment: @Plutonix I would think the same thing, but everything in above code is all new... Even if the `DataSource` is not cleared, setting it again would wipe other ...

Comment: Try adding a `Distinct` to your query...

Comment: You dont need that loop at the bottom at all; those only need to be set once for the control not for each row

Comment: there's no data table :\ jst data set ! @plutonix

Comment: ...and what do you think is inside a dataset?

Comment: I use the Distinct  but the same error :\

Comment: not quite, but what line do you get the error on?

Comment: not in specific line ,,, it make a new page ... and the header "source not available"